# Correct MD5 hash to decode resources hashes

Tags: c#, hash, evernote

I am trying to decode the value I find in  tags "hash" attribute, like "b4002e70b6cb73b1093d83e2b8e6c734", to a byte array so I can call the noteStore.getResourceByHash method correctly. Right now I am constantly getting EDAMNotFoundException errors, so I am guessing I am not computing the hash correctly.

Did anyone already figure this out?

Here is the code. I tried many different methods. This is the current state of affairs:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider test123 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b4002e70b6cb73b1093d83e2b8e6c733");
data = test123.ComputeHash(data);
var note = noteStore.getResourceByHash(evernoteToken, noteGuid, data, true, false, false);
```

Comment: Done. Please see edits. Please remove the down vote...? :-)

Comment: a fully reproducible example would be best.

Comment: Probably you need hex decoding, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: MD5 is a *very very* poor algorithm to uniquely identify resources.

Comment: CodesInChaos' comment helped me along, together with this link: https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/63123-inline-resources-are-not-displayed/?k=880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024&setlanguage=1&langid=4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your hexadecimal number is 16 bytes. Is it a GUID? If so, you can just use this:

```
var id = Guid.Parse("b4002e70b6cb73b1093d83e2b8e6c733").ToByteArray();
```

Using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` is definitely not right, because that will get you a `byte` per `char`, corresponding to the ASCII value for that character. You want a `byte` per two `char` (hexadecimal decoding).

Answer (score 0):

Evernote references resources via the resource's GUID or the *hash of the binary file stream*.

If you are looking to get the hash of a resource, you must take the hash of the file you have uploaded to Evernote.  The code might look something like this:

```
    public string CalculateFileHashTotal(string fileLocation)
            {
                using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileLocation))
                    {
                        byte[] b = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                        stream.Close();
                        return BitConverter.ToString(B).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
```

If you are looking to get a resource that has already been uploaded or you don't have access to the file, referencing the resource via the GUID would likely be your best option.

You can call the `getNote` method to get the note object which will have the attribute `resources` which contains a list of `Resources` each of has the attribute GUID.  This GUID can be used to call any of the following methods (each is linked to Evernote API reference):

- [getResource](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResource)
- [getResourceAlternateData](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceAlternateData)
- [getResourceApplicationData](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceApplicationData)
- [getResourceApplicationDataEntry](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceApplicationDataEntry)
- [getResourceAttributes](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceAttributes)
- [getResourceData](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceData)
- [getResourceRecognition](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceRecognition)
- [getResourceSearchText](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceSearchText)